# Reply body conditioned by mailbox it is sent from

Tags: vba, outlook, conditional-statements, signature

So I have multiple mailboxes under my Outlook account and I am trying to get them to generate reply template based on the mailbox I am replying from (one is private, one is shared). I have tried to base the condition on *SenderName* and *SenderEmailAddress*, but to no avail (reply email gets generated with the contents of the previous email retrieved but the text I intend to put in front of it is not there; the cause is that the value of *oReply.SenderEmailAddress* is empty as *Else* clause will write the stuff as intended).

(and yes, there are snippets from code enabling reply with attachments)

```
Sub ReplyWithAttachments()
    Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim sSignature As String

    Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()
    If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
        Set oReply = oItem.Reply

        If oReply.SenderEmailAddress = "mailbox.private@something.com" Then
            sSignature = "Hello and welcome!"
        ElseIf oReply.SenderEmailAddress = "mailbox.shared@something.com" Then
            sSignature = "Go to hell!"        
        End If

        CopyAttachments oItem, oReply
        oReply.HTMLBody = sSignature & oReply.HTMLBody
        oReply.Display
        oItem.UnRead = False
    End If

    Set oReply = Nothing
    Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
so I managed to get somewhere with

```
Set oReply = oItem.Reply
sMailBox = oReply.Sender.GetExchangeUser.Address

If sMailBox = "mailbox.private@something.com" Then
    sSignature = "whatever"
ElseIf sMailBox = "mailbox.shared@something.com" Then
    sSignature = "bla bla bla"
Else
    sSignature = "Something"
```

The code works as intended for the shared mailbox but for the private one, it errors out with *Object variable or With block variable not set* pointing to .*Sender*

```
sMailBox = oReply.Sender.GetExchangeUser.Address
```

Comment: When you say **to no avail**, what does it actually do? does it not match the either of the emails you specified? if not then what email address does `oReply.SenderEmailAddress` return?

Answer (score 1):

I have something that I use to get sender email (as its dependent on your email exchange)

```
Dim strSendersEmailAddress As String

If oItem.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
    strSendersEmailAddress = oItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
    strSendersEmailAddress = oItem.SenderEmailAddress
End If
```

You will have to get the email address before you `Set oReply = oItem.Reply`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, however this retreives sender address of the original email. I am essentially trying to retrieve *my own* sender address (the mailbox I intend to send the reply from) and use this to determine the appropriate mail contents.

Comment: Hey! this actually **had** some merit! I was able to use this to the *oReply* object and get the email address of the shared mailbox (there is some problem for the private one but I think I will be able to resolve it eventually).

Comment: Try this `oReply.Sendusingaccount.smtpaddress`

Comment: This always retrieves the address of the private mailbox (both the mailboxes are under the same account). Updating question with current progress.

Comment: Had a quick look and found this: `oReply.Session.Accounts.Item(1).DisplayName`. I think as there will only ever be 1 account for `oReply` session, it should give you the email address. Saying that, as I only have 1 account in my mailbox, I cannot properly test it

Comment: Again, this gave just the address of the private mailbox. Anyway - my solution is to use the original code snippet with *On Error*. The stuff works well for shared mailboxes and I do not expect users having more than one non-shared mailbox, so the private signature can be left in a simple *Else*.